# How to test Dart's package made for both client and server side?

Tags: testing, dart

I'm making a library that provides both client & server side code. When making the tests, I would like to test the interactions from both sides.

So far I have at least this tests:

Server side:

```
@TestOn("vm")
import "package:test/test.dart";
import "dart:io";
//...
void main() {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.LOOPBACK_IP_V4, 4040)
    //.then()...
```

Cliente side:

```
@TestOn("content-shell")
import "package:test/test.dart";
import "dart:html";
//...
void main(){
    //Interact with server at 4040
```

What should I do to have all the tests ran with a single command? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [the docs](https://github.com/dart-lang/test/tree/master/doc) provided by Günter, create *dart_test.yaml* in the package's root:

```
#dart_test.yaml

#run 2 test suites at the same time (I guess, that in 2 different cores)
concurrency: 2
```

Now run

> pub run test test/server.dart test/client.dart -pvm,content-shell

If it takes long (generally on opening the browser) you could add to the same config file:

```
timeout: none #or i.e., 1m 30s
```

You can also save the *-pvm,content-shell* part of the command by seizing the config file:

```
platforms:
- vm
- content-shell
```

If this doesn't work, you could save the hours it took me figuring out what the heck happened by running:

> pub cache repair

Answer (score 3):

`@TestOn("content-shell")` doesn't make much sense in my opinion, except when this test shouldn't be run in other browsers. Use `browser` instead.

Without `@TestOn()` (default) the tests will be run on any platform. Only add `@TestOn(...)` if you want to restrict where the test is run.

To run browser tests and server tests with a single command use

```
pub run test -pvm -pdartium -pchrome -pfirefox -pie -pblink
```

or a bit shorter

```
pub run test -pvm,dartium,chrome,firefox,ie,blink
```

The [readme](https://github.com/dart-lang/test) and the docs in https://github.com/dart-lang/test/tree/master/doc provide lots of details how to configure the test runner.

Comment: _pub run test -pvm,content-shell_ worked well and the docs helped me find the solution, thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear. Thanks for the feedback :)